# Not able to assign child VC properties in Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I was able to do it in swift as expected but where as same functionality is required to do in objective C not able to set child VC properties.

Here is the swift code it works as expected.

```
    if let feedbackNavVc =
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
            identifier: "PremiumFeedbackNavViewController"
        ) as? PremiumCustomNavigationController {
        if let feedbackVc = feedbackNavVc.children.first as? PremiumFeedbackViewController {
            feedbackVc.id = self.fileDetails?.id
            feedbackVc.pageNumber = self.currentPageNumber
            feedbackVc.pageCount = self.totalPageCount
            present(feedbackNavVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I've tried to do it in objective C but not able to set properties inside child VC. If we can convert above swift code to objective C that would be fine.

```
            NSString * storyboardName = @"Premium";
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
            UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PremiumFeedbackNavViewController"];
            UIViewController * feedbackVC = vc.childViewControllers.firstObject;
            //feedbackVC.id = self.objectId;  ///Error: Property id not found on object of type UIViewController
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How to assign child view controller properties in objective C?

Comment: `as?`, that's a cast. So `UIViewController * feedbackVC = vc.childViewControllers.firstObject;` should be `PremiumFeedbackViewController * feedbackVC =  (PremiumFeedbackViewController *) vc.childViewControllers.firstObject;` Same for `vc` and `PremiumCustomnavigationController` logic.

Comment: There is a `if let` to ensure the class, thing that you might do with a `isKindOfClass:` test.

Comment: I'm new to Objective C if you can add as answer that will be possible to mark as answer and uncomplicated.

Comment: Title should be: how to cast pointers in Objective-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Objective-C code you tried, there is no mention of `PremiumCustomNavigationController` or `PremiumFeedbackViewController`, just the base class `UIViewController`.
You are telling the instance are `UIViewController`, so how should you be able to acess specific properties of `PremiumFeedbackViewController`?

You need to clearly understand what you are doing in Swift to translate it.

```
if let a = b as? SomeClass {
}
```

You are testing if `a` can be an instance of `SomeClass`.

So in Objective-C, this would be:

```
if ([a isKindOfClass:[SomeClass class]]) {
    SomeClass *b = (SomeClass *)a;
}
```

if let feedbackNavVc =
storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
identifier: "PremiumFeedbackNavViewController"
) as? PremiumCustomNavigationController {
if let feedbackVc = feedbackNavVc.children.first as? PremiumFeedbackViewController {
feedbackVc.id = self.fileDetails?.id
feedbackVc.pageNumber = self.currentPageNumber
feedbackVc.pageCount = self.totalPageCount
present(feedbackNavVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

Should be then:

```
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PremiumFeedbackNavViewController"];

if ([vc isKindOfClass: [PremiumCustomNavigationController class]]) {
    PremiumCustomNavigationController *feedbackNavVc =  (PremiumCustomNavigationController *)vc;
    UIViewController *firstChild = [feedbackNavVc.childViewControllers firstObject];
    if ([firstChild isKindOfClass: [PremiumFeedbackViewController class]]) {
        PremiumFeedbackViewController *feedbackVc = (PremiumFeedbackViewController *)firstChild;
        feedbackVc.id = self.fileDetails.id
        feedbackVc.pageNumber = self.currentPageNumber
        feedbackVc.pageCount = self.totalPageCount
    }
}
```

Now, if you are sure about the classes, you can skip the `isKindOfClass:` and directly put the cast.

```
PremiumCustomNavigationController *feedbackNavVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PremiumFeedbackNavViewController"];
PremiumFeedbackViewController *feedbackVc = [feedbackNavVc. childViewControllers firstObject]; // (0)
feedbackVc.id = self.fileDetails.id // (1)
feedbackVc.pageNumber = self.currentPageNumber
feedbackVc.pageCount = self.totalPageCount
```

If you aren't sure about your classes, it will crash at `(1)` with "-[SomeClassOfViewController id] unrecognized selector sent to instance".
It won't crash at `(0)`, because `feedbackNavVc`, even if it's not an instance of `PremiumCustomNavigationController`, it's a `UIViewController` (or nil, but then no issue). And a `UIViewController` has a property `childViewControllers`, so it's legit. In fact, you shouldn't need to cast to `PremiumCustomNavigationController` here (nor in Swift).

Comment: It thows an error as Property 'children' not found on object of type 'PremiumCustomNavigationController  at this part of code [feedbackNavVc.children firstObject];

Comment: Should be fixed. It's named `childViewControllers` in Objective-C, I forgot. You wrote it correctly in your attempt.

Comment: I made it to this [feedbackNavVc.childViewControllers firstObject]; then the error is on ///Error: Property id not found on object of type PremiumFeedbackViewController and i don't need pageNumber and pageCount required only id.

Comment: What's the declaration of `PremiumFeedbackViewController`? Is `id` visible? Ah, it should be renamed, since `id` is a guarded term. What does say the bridge file: "YourAppName-Swift.h" There should be mention of `PremiumFeedbackViewController` somewhere...

Comment: I can get outlets of the VC as feedbackVc.pageNoLabel but not the declared properties id declared as open var id: String!

Comment: What's `"YourAppName-Swift.h"` looking like for `PremiumFeedbackViewController`? You must have an `#import` of that header somewhere, look into that file. You should renamed `id` since it's reserved...

Comment: PremiumFeedbackViewController is in swift and it was not imported in bridging header and the current calling Objective c VC is imported.

Comment: If `PremiumFeedbackViewController` is in Swift, to use it inside Objective-C, it needs to be `"YourAppName-Swift.h"`, don't you have `#import "YourAppName-Swift.h"` somewhere?

Comment: I've done it in some other way,  I've understood the concept here so marking it as answer. Thank you.